# How do you replace a specific value of an input field using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following input fields in a form. I would like remove undefined and replace it with a blank space "". I can't seem to get it to work. I only would like to remove "undefined" not original value.

```
<input type="hidden" name="address1" id="address1" value="Some address undefined" class="address1">

<input type="hidden" name="address2" id="address2" value="Another address undefined" class="address1">
```

I would only like to remove undefined. So far I've tried:

```
var str = $('input').value().replace(/undefined/g, 'ada');
$('input').value(str);
```

and

```
$('input:contains("undefined")').each(function(){ 
     $(this).html($(this).html().split("undefined").join(""));
});
```

Comment: These hidden inputs are obviously used in a form and not displayed (ie: hidden") - so leave the undefined in and deal with it at the destination of the form (ie: in the php page that the form passes its data to- faster than trying to modify the value client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$('input').val()` not `$('input').value()` with `jQuery`'s `each()`.

```js
$('input').each(function(i, el){
  var str = $(el).val().replace(/undefined/g, '');
  console.log(str);
  $('input').val(str);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="address1" id="address1" value="Some address undefined" class="address1">

<input type="hidden" name="address2" id="address2" value="Another address undefined" class="address1">
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `value()`, which doesn't exist in the jQuery API. Use [**val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/) instead. On top of this you should iterate through each input via, `each()` and target the individual input of the current iteration using `this`.

```js
$('input').each(function() {
  var str = $(this).val().replace(/undefined/g, 'ada');

  $(this).val(str);

  console.log(
    $(this).val()
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" name="address1" id="address1" value="Some address undefined" class="address1" />

<input type="hidden" name="address2" id="address2" value="Another address undefined" class="address1" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The thing about this is it's replacing the current value. I only would like to replace 'undefined" Not the entire value

Comment: @Mariton Revised my answer.

Comment: Thank you all of these answers were helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Use `.val()`, not `.value()`. You can give it a function as the argument. It will call this function with the old value as the argument, and the return value will be used as the new value (so you don't need to use `.each()` as in the other answers).

```js
$("#click").click(function() {
  $("input").val(function(i, oldvalue) {
    return oldvalue.replace(/undefined/g, '');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="address1" id="address1" value="Some address undefined" class="address1">

<input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" value="Another address undefined" class="address1">
<br>
<button id="click">Click to change</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
$('input').val("");
```

instead of

```
var str = $('input').val().replace(/undefined/g, 'ada');
$('input').val(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each one of them using `each`.

```js
$('input').each(function(){
  $this = $(this);
  $this.val($this.val().replace(/undefined/g, ''))
  console.log('new value is : ', $this.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" name="address1" id="address1" value="Some address undefined" class="address1">
<input type="hidden" name="address2" id="address2" value="Another address undefined" class="address1">
```